# Redis Sentinel failover not happenning as excpected

Tags: redis

I setup a Redis replication and Redis Sentinel.
As far as I can see all is configured well.

This is redis-sentinel.conf on the master:

```
sentinel myid c975aac973e325412d2a70a5b9f6195fcb9e40e7
sentinel deny-scripts-reconfig yes
sentinel monitor redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redisoctcluster 5000

# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
port 26379
dir "/etc/redis"
protected-mode no
sentinel failover-timeout redisoctcluster 60000
sentinel config-epoch redisoctcluster 0
sentinel leader-epoch redisoctcluster 11
sentinel known-replica redisoctcluster 10.103.19.57 6360
sentinel known-sentinel redisoctcluster 10.103.19.57 26379 fd19cf80e9b23db1501d9bfcc01aaff711a7b44b

sentinel current-epoch 11
```

And this is redis-sentinel.conf on the slave:

```
sentinel myid fd19cf80e9b23db1501d9bfcc01aaff711a7b44b
sentinel deny-scripts-reconfig yes
#bind 0.0.0.0
sentinel monitor redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redisoctcluster 5000
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis-sentinel.log"
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
port 26379
dir "/etc/redis"
protected-mode no
sentinel failover-timeout redisoctcluster 60000
sentinel config-epoch redisoctcluster 0
sentinel leader-epoch redisoctcluster 11
sentinel known-replica redisoctcluster 10.103.19.57 6360
sentinel known-sentinel redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 26379 c975aac973e325412d2a70a5b9f6195fcb9e40e7

sentinel current-epoch 11
```

As far as i can see using redis-cli for sentinel (on both master and slave) - all is good:

```
# redis-cli -p 26379 info sentinel
# Sentinel
sentinel_masters:1
sentinel_tilt:0
sentinel_running_scripts:0
sentinel_scripts_queue_length:0
sentinel_simulate_failure_flags:0
master0:name=redisoctcluster,status=ok,address=10.97.7.140:6360,slaves=1,sentinels=2
```

Running get-master-addr-by-name on the slave shows it knows the master:

```
# redis-cli -p 26379 sentinel get-master-addr-by-name  redisoctcluster
1) "10.97.7.140"
2) "6360"
```

Still when I stop Redis on the master, I see this in sentinel logs:

```
 # +odown master redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360 #quorum 2/2
 # +new-epoch 10
 # +try-failover master redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360
 # +vote-for-leader fd19cf80e9b23db1501d9bfcc01aaff711a7b44b 10
 # c975aac973e325412d2a70a5b9f6195fcb9e40e7 voted for fd19cf80e9b23db1501d9bfcc01aaff711a7b44b 10
 # +elected-leader master redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360
 # +failover-state-select-slave master redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360
 # -failover-abort-no-good-slave master redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360
 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Sun Nov  8 16:34:42 2020
```

What is wrong with my confoiguration preventing the failover from happenning?

Comment: I see now in the log that it says the slave is down:                                                                  **# +sdown slave 10.103.19.57:6360 10.103.19.57 6360 @ redisoctcluster 10.97.7.140 6360**
this explains why the failover couldn't occur... still don't understand wht the it says the slave is down when all looks OK

Answer (score 0):

Had to change bind parameter in both redis.conf file and redis-sentinel.conf file to 0.0.0.0 for the problem to go away:
bind 0.0.0.0

Then both the "sdown" notification disappeared and the failover occured.